# js fatal error - output nri in addtcart

Tags: javascript

i want to echo the nri variable in the second formData var, like this:

```
    var formData = {
        'nri'         : $('input[name=nri]').val(),
        'addtcart'    : $('input[name=addtcart'.nri.']').val()
    };
```

Example: if nri is 1, the addtcart is input[name=addtcart1].
I have a error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: use `+` instead of `.` for string concatenation.

Comment: $('input[name=addtcart' + nri + ']').val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `+` sign instead of `.` for string concatenation, and do it in two steps to access the `nri` value:

```
var formData = {
    'nri'         : $('input[name=nri]').val(),
};
formData.addtcart = $('input[name=addtcart' + formData.nri + ']').val()
```